# converting a string to date and formatiing to MS access 2007 database

Tags: java, ms-access-2007

HI i have a application connecting to the MS access database.
the date is passed as a string from the jsp .
i am converting the string to date as follows

`strtDate` is the date in string format (eg 4/18/2011 in MM/dd/yyyy format)

```
DateFormat convDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");       
java.util.Date conDate = (Date) convDate.parse(strtDate);
java.sql.Date convSqlDate = new java.sql.Date(conDate.getTime());
```

the `convSqlDate` value am getting as 2011-04-18.

In MS access the data type of date is Date/Time.

how to convert this date to MM/dd/yyyy format.

Answer (score 1):

The formatting doesn't matter once you have a `Date` object to insert into the database.  The JDBC driver will take care of all the details to ensure that your object is stored properly in MS SQL Server.

Formatting matters when you render the `Date`, but you should have no problems once you've converted.

Comment: if i hardcode the date value as in database format ie 4/18/2011 i can fetch the details .if in any other format ,it does not retrieve the details

Comment: I don't understand what "hardcode the date" means if you have a java.util.Date.